# How to update auto-increment field after removing a row?

Tags: mysql

I have auto increment fields in mysql database, that is my **id** when I remove on of the my items the next field id is starting after deleted number.

**For Example:**
my content from 1 to 100, when I remove these contents (from 1 to 100), and insert other contents, The **id** is *101*, I need the **id** to be *1* and start from *1* again or start from the smaller number in MySQL id field

*EDIT:* **I have a CMS , in CMS the user can delete some rows, and I need other auto increment update automaticaly**

Comment: There is no option in MySQL to reset the auto increment automatically when rows are deleted. Also, the auto increment is always required to be higher than the highest value in the column, it will never fill in gaps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is no option in MySQL to do this, but if you have a CMS and need to sorting auto-increment fields by MySQL, I know a better way that is fetching auto-increment fields value and put them in an array and then work with that array, for example This is your database table:

```
id  |  name
```

and this is the value of your table:

```
25  | Ali
36  | Alex
37  | Reza
39  | Steven
40  | Mohammad
```

Then fetch this values and put them in array and then work for that from 0 to the end (count of fields on table):

for example You can have access to the each value what you want from 0 to end:

```
echo $array[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE yourTableName AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If you always all rows remove from table so you can fire manually truncate query like:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE  table_name;
```

so after deletion rows your field auto increment start from 1 to end.

i hope this help you.

Answer (score -3):

```
ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
```

but be carefull with setting the auto increment field manually because it is intended to identify the each column Uniquely. If you want to start again from 1 i think its better to use that in a scenario where you have deleted all your data and want to insert again

Comment: No No, I have a CMS , in CMS the user can delete some rows, and I need other auto increment update automaticaly

Comment: It doesn't happen automatically. Never ever.